# Pcchips p17g motherboard will not detect SSD

Tags: bios

I am putting together a system with 3 hard drives and an SSD. The motherboard detect the hard drives, but not the SSD. I've swapped data cables, power cables and there is no change.

The motherboard is a dated board, a PC chips p17g.

I have tried several different SSD, and it will not detect any of them. However if I use a USB converter, the SSD is recognized right away through the USB interface.

The target system will be slackware, however this problem is really a hardware problem. Has anyone had anything similar?

Comment: This has nothing to do with UNIX I guess. Better ask in the specialized hardware forums. The mobo may need a new BIOS if it exists, or it may just not work with SSDs and that will be the end of it.

Comment: Perhaps the SSD is broken... it *should* look like a run-of-the-mill disk to the mobo.

Comment: The SSD works fine on other systems, and I tried several other SSDs.  Eventually, I booted up the OS form a hard drive, and sometimes it recognized the SSD, and other times it didn't. I am curious as to why, but the game will change, as I have decided to swap in yet another MB.